# Rewrite non-www to www without rewriting any subdomain in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Rewrite non-www to www without rewriting any subdomain in .htaccess. Ex: sample.com to www.sample.com. subdomains.sample.com still stays the same. Does not change to www.sudomains.sample.com

Also how do I rewrite a subdirectory to a specific file/page via 301? Ive tried a few methods but didn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sample\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

> Also how do I rewrite a subdirectory to a specific file/page via 301?

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^subdirectory(/.*)?$ /page.php [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.